# VC2010 Change Auto List Members

Tags: visual-studio-2010, highlight, fill, members

Anyone know how to change the Auto List Member highlight from yellow to whatever? I'm currently using the VC2010 C++ edition. Its difficult to see the highlight vs my other font colors. Thanks :D